# How do I set cron using performance page?

Tags: 7, performance

I am not able to set up the performance setting for cron duration, and automatic cache clearing setting in admin performance page.

I am not able to find the exact issue. I am clearing the cache manually everyday currently.

Can anyone provide better solution for this?

I changed the settings, and clicked on the save button of the form,but settings are not saved. This happen with both cron and cache duration settings.

Comment: if the cache / performance settings aren't being saved - there would be an error reported somewhere (sounds like a database error). Check your error logs and update your question with the error your are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to Cron Settings (*http://example.com/drupal7/admin/config/system/cron*) to set it, default is 3 hours.

Comment: I changed the settings and submitted. But settings not saved in drupal 7. This happen both cron and cache duration settings